# Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and .Net 5.0, however I'm a newbie, so please talk to me like to a newbie. I downloaded a library from GitHub and included it sucesfully to my project - Visual Studio sees both the library and functions from the library. However the code doesn't compile. I obtain `Duplicate 'global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' attribute` error. More specifically I obtain 3 such errors (I've got 3 `.csproj` files, however the Visual Studio always says it concerns one project (sometimes this, sometimes another)).

I googled this error and most people advise to add `<GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>` to the `.csproj` file, but it doesn't work for me. I'm adding this line everywhere like a maniac, but only one error disappeared - there are two now. Here is how it looks like: [image]

Some people advise to also add some other lines, but it doesn't work for me either. `CreepyGnome` out here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12297 wrote that he delated the directory and re-cloned the repository (from GitHub?) and it worked for him without adding any lines, but I don't know what it exactly means, because, as I said, I'm a newbie.

Please help me to get rid of this, because I'm going to lose my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following an advice from another thread I solved the problem. I'll write it here, because it's maybe not enough clear there:

1. I added two lines:

```xml
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>   
<GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
```

to **all** `.csproj` files of my projects betweeen `<PropertyGroup>` and `</PropertyGroup>`.

2. I delated all `bin` ond `obj` folders in my projects.

**The crucial thing is to do both these things and in exactly this order.** When I only added the lines, it didn't help much. When I delated the directories it worked once till the second compilation. When I tried to compile it second time - it stopped working, because compilation creates bin and obj directories.

Comment: Hi Plrc, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Ok, I accepted it as an aswer :D I hope it will help others.

Comment: <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>  . Needed this. That was a weird episode, one minute fine, the next it was impossible to build without this. Still don't know why I have duplicate Info but not worried, thanks.